# Прекращение работы Python из-за программы с PyQt5 (Используется QThread и MoveToThread). Как решить данную проблему?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qthread

Пытаюсь освоить многопоточность *PyQt*, но пока кое-что не получается. Подскажите, по какой причине во время исполнения данного фрагмента кода *Python* прекращает работу. Или хотя бы может поможете правильно организовать многопоточную работу программы.

```
from design import MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread
import sys
import algorithm


class AlgThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
        super(AlgThread, self).__init__()
        self.font_name = font_name
        self.lang = lang
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.open_ = open_

    def run(self):
        algorithm.make_prescription(self.font_name, self.lang, self.save_path, self.open_)


def saving(font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
    thread = QThread()
    alg = AlgThread(font_name, lang, save_path, open_)
    alg.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(alg.run)
    thread.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.saving_sgl.connect(saving)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: честно говоря я не знаю как мой большой код сделать минимально воспроизводимым. Тут он самодостаточный для устного понимания. Или вам никак не обойтись без рабочей версии?

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `design.py` расскажите что такое `algorithm` - что делает и как установить.

Comment: вы можете хоть как-то прокомментировать мой ответ?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Сегодня утром увидел, днем опробовал. Попробовал добавить thread = QThread(window), в таком случае метод run даже не выполняется в ходе программы. Тем не менее я благодарен вам за ответ

Comment: вы не обратили внимание на мои добавления `QThread.msleep(...)`

Comment: А, действительно, так всё работает. Я подумал это просто для наглядности (симуляция какого-то процесса). Спасибо вам большое, пойду почитаю об этой функции

Comment: вот это важно `QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: saving(...)`, т.к. вызов функции `saving` должен произойти, после запуска основного цикла `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: Если вас не затруднит, можете объяснить, почему без QThread.msleep данный код не работает?

Comment: я же вам написал -  вызов функции `saving` должен произойти, после запуска основного цикла

Comment: Я вас не совсем понимаю. В своем изначальном коде я сделал следующие изменения: заменил thread = QThread() на thread = QThread(window), и добавил оба вызова функции QThread.msleep, в тех же местах, что и в вашем решении. Так вот, при запуске этого скрипта у нас сначала запускается основной цикл, и лишь потом при генерации сигнала saving_sgl вызывается saving. Тем не менее без msleep данный код не работает. Почему?

Comment: для того чтобы не было множества вопросов `почему`, я вам и написал первые два комментария. А что вы мне ответили? Просто у вас код написан не совсем правильно и я в своем ответе не менял сути, приведенного вами примера, а только сделал чтобы он работал. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, задайте новый вопрос, приложите минимально-воспроизводимый приме и расскажите что у вас не получается.

Comment: @S.Nick https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1254159/409675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `saving()` вы создаете объект `thread` :

```
thread = QThread()
```

`thread` - это **локальна** переменная и удаляется сборщиком мусора.
Чтобы продлить ей жизнь, нужен родитель:

```
    thread = QThread(window)
```

---

```
import sys
# ? from design import MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow                          # + QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, QTimer                              # + QTimer
# ? import algorithm


class AlgThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
        super(AlgThread, self).__init__()
        self.font_name = font_name
        self.lang = lang
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.open_ = open_

    def run(self):
#        algorithm.make_prescription(self.font_name, self.lang, self.save_path, self.open_)
        QThread.msleep(3000)                               # имитируем какой-то процесс 3 секунды
        print(f"\ndef run(self): {self.font_name}, {self.lang}, {self.save_path}, {self.open_}")


def saving(font_name, lang, save_path, open_, window):                           # +++ window
    thread = QThread(window)                                                     # +++ window
    alg = AlgThread(font_name, lang, save_path, open_)
    alg.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(alg.run)
    thread.start()
    QThread.msleep(100)                                                          # +++


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# window = MainWindow()
window = QMainWindow()                                                            # +

# window.saving_sgl.connect(saving)
window.show()

font_name, lang, save_path, open_ = 1, 2, 3, 4                                    # +
QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: saving(font_name, lang, save_path, open_, window))  # +++ window

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]