# Почему данный код многопоточного приложения не работает? (Используется QThread, moveToThread)

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, pyqt, qthread

Подскажите почему данный код не работает и не вывод ничего в консоль? 
Видимо я ещё недостаточно силен в многопоточности. Если есть советы по написанию кода, то буду рад поучиться.

**main.pyw**

```
from design import MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread
import sys
import algorithm


class AlgThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
        super(AlgThread, self).__init__()
        self.font_name = font_name
        self.lang = lang
        self.save_path = save_path
        self.open_ = open_

    def run(self):
        algorithm.make_prescription(self.font_name, self.lang, self.save_path, self.open_)


def saving(font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
    thread = QThread(window)
    alg = AlgThread(font_name, lang, save_path, open_)
    alg.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(alg.run)
    thread.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.saving_sgl.connect(saving)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    saving_sgl = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str, str, bool)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(200, 150)
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Отправить')
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.creating_file)

    def creating_file(self):
        f, t, p, o = 'hello', 'my', 'friend', True  # Эти переменные берут данные из сторонних источников
        self.saving_sgl.emit(f, t, p, o)
```

**algorithm.py**

```
def make_prescription(font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
    print(font_name, lang, save_path, open_)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я немного изменил ваш код и прокомментировал его:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal

        
#import algorithm
def make_prescription(font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
    print(f'\n def make_prescription: {font_name}, {lang}, {save_path}, {open_}')
    return [font_name, lang, save_path, open_]                                         # +++


class AlgThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self):                             # - , font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
        super(AlgThread, self).__init__()
        self.font_name = ''
        self.lang = ''
        self.save_path = ''
        self.open_ = False                                                   
        
    def run(self):
        while True:                            
            if self.open_:   # если условный `self.open_` истина, то сделаем какие-то действия
                                
                #algorithm.make_prescription(self.font_name, self.lang, self.save_path, self.open_)
                
                # для теста сделал паузу, как-будто запрос выполняется 2 сек 
                QThread.msleep(2000)                          # (уберите)
                
                rez = make_prescription(self.font_name, self.lang, self.save_path, self.open_)
                # возможно вам понадобится передавать `rez` в основной поток (сигналы и слоты)
                self.open_ = False    # запрос выполнен и мы отключились. Ждем следующего клика. 
            QThread.msleep(100)        


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    saving_sgl = pyqtSignal(str, str, str, bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.btn = QPushButton('Отправить')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.creating_file)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        
        self.saving_sgl.connect(self.saving)

        # формируем и запускает дополнительный поток, 
        # который все время в работе, 
        # но запрос в нем будет выполняться только по клику 
        # и при передачей условной переменной `open_ = True`
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.alg = AlgThread()                      
        self.alg.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.alg.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def creating_file(self):
        # Эти переменные берут данные из сторонних источников
        f, t, p, o = 'hello', 'my', 'friend', True  
        self.saving_sgl.emit(f, t, p, o)
        
    def saving(self, font_name, lang, save_path, open_):
        self.alg.font_name = font_name
        self.alg.lang = lang
        self.alg.save_path = save_path
        self.alg.open_ = open_
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(200, 150)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Хочу еще спросить, оптимально ли то, что поток всё время работает. Я новичок, не знаю как там всё устроено, но звучит как неоптимальное использование ресурсов)) Так ли это?

Comment: @Paitor да вы правильно подметили. я добавил в метод `run` - `QThread.msleep(100)`, теперь все ок.